# R: Recreate historical membership from a list of changes in membership

Tags: r, set

Suppose I have the current membership status of a group, i.e. names of members. Additionally, I have data on times when some new member may have been added to the group and / or an old member may have been removed from the group.

The task at hand is to recreate the membership of the group at all these points in time. I've looked around but did not find a ready solution for this problem. Does anybody know an elegant method of doing this?

### Reproducible example:

Input:

```
periods <- 5
indx <- paste0("t-", seq_len(periods))
[1] "t-1" "t-2" "t-3" "t-4" "t-5"

current <- letters[seq_len(10)]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

incoming <- setNames(letters[seq_len(periods) + 5], indx)
incoming[2] <- NA
t-1 t-2 t-3 t-4 t-5
"f"  NA "h" "i" "j"

outgoing <- setNames(letters[seq_len(periods) + 10], indx)
outgoing[4] <- NA
t-1 t-2 t-3 t-4 t-5
"k" "l" "m"  NA "o"
```

Output:

```
$current
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"

$`t-1`
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k"

$`t-2`
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l"

$`t-3`
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "g" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m"

$`t-4`
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "g" "j" "k" "l" "m"

$`t-5`
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "g" "k" "l" "m" "o"
```

---

Disclaimer: I've written a solution for this which I will be posting as my answer to the question. The intent is to document this problem and *a possible* solution and to elicit other  ingenious and / or existing solutions or improvements.

Comment: Is this the exact form of the data? Or are you reading them in from some other format?

Comment: What is the desired use-case for it? Should the program be able to answer a query of "who was in the group at epoch N" ? Because storing the epoch-specific lists could get memory intensive, I'd look into storing the diff list over the epochs and storing the original list. just a matter of applying a few diffs to answer  the question later.

Comment: @Thomas: This is the data that I am generating to test this solution. Other structures can be used as well.

Comment: @Shark: The use case is to recreate the membership of stocks in a financial index. Also, see related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17569577/r-create-a-function-method-for-all-possible-time-series-classes . I will think about what you are saying.

Comment: think of a 100 element long list that drops rand(100) elements over a 1000 epochs. Is it better to save 1000 membership lists, or a starting membership list and 1000 diffs, which you'd just apply to the list sequentially? Additionally, one could hold a 'master diff' list, which is the aggregate of all the previous difs but as a one-diff change. This allows for benefit of knowing the 'current' (latest) membership list by applying only one diff change. But calculating the master diff is something i got nothing on right now :)

Comment: I understand and appreciate the procedure you have explained. I need to figure out if saving the whole membership or only the diffs will be more useful in my use case. But, we'll definitely have to write functions to generate the master diff and calculate a particular time-stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `create_mem_ts` (membership timeseries) will generate the desired output as posted in the question.

```
create_mem_ts <- function (ctime, added, removed, current) {

  # Create a time-series of membership of a set.

  # Inputs:

  ## ctime:     Time of changes in set.
  ##            An atomic vector of a time-series class or otherwise,
  ##
  ##            interpretable as a time-series in descending order (for e.g.
  ##            `t-1`, `t-2`, `t-3` etc.
  ##
  ##            Is an index of when the changes in membership happened in time.
  ##            Allows repeats but no NAs.

  ## added:     Member(s) added to the set.
  ##            An atomic vector or a list of the same length as ctime.
  ##
  ##            If an atomic vector, represents exactly one member added at
  ##            the corresponding ctime.
  ##
  ##            If a list, represents multiple members added at corresponding
  ##            ctime.

  ## removed:   Member(s) removed from the set.
  ##            An atomic vector or a list of the same length as ctime.
  ##
  ##            If an atomic vector, represents exactly one member removed at
  ##            the corresponding ctime.
  ##
  ##            If a list, represents multiple members removed at the
  ##            corresponding ctime.

  ## current:   Current membership of the set.
  ##            An atomic vector listing the current membership of the set.

  # Output:

  ## A list of the same length as ctime named by values in ctime (coerced to
  ## character by the appropriate method). 

  stopifnot(is.atomic(ctime),
            is.atomic(added) || is.list(added),
            is.atomic(removed) || is.list(removed))

  if (any(is.na(ctime))) stop("NAs not allowed in the ctime.")

  stopifnot(length(ctime) == length(added),
            length(added) == length(removed))

  if (any(duplicated(ctime))) {
    ctime.u <- unique(ctime)
    ctime.f <- factor(ctime, levels=as.character(ctime.u))
    added <- split(added, ctime.f)
    removed <- split(removed, ctime.f)
  } else {
    ctime.u <- ctime
  }

  out <- setNames(vector(mode="list", length=length(ctime.u) + 1),
                  c("current", as.character(ctime.u)))
  out[["current"]] <- current

  for (i in 2:length(out))
    out[[i]] <- union(setdiff(out[[i - 1]], added[[i - 1]]),
                      na.omit(removed[[i - 1]]))

  attr(out, "index") <- ctime.u

  out

}
```

Moreover, if `ctime` is a valid time-series class in the function above, the output from that can be used to generate membership on any time-stamp using the function (within the range in ctime) using this function `memship_at`.

```
memship_at <- function (mem_ts, at) {

  stopifnot(inherits(at, class(attr(mem_ts, "index"))))

  just.before <- which(at > attr(mem_ts, "index"))[1]

  if (just.before > 1)
    mem_ts[[just.before - 1]]
  else
    mem_ts[[1]]

}
```